# Python: Referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I receive the following error `local variable 'ticket_reservation_expired' referenced before assignment`. Anyone knows how to resolve this?

I think a solution could be to assign `ticket_reservation_expired = ""`before calling the function, but I wonder if that is the best way to resolve this?

helpers.py

```
def ticket_reservation_expired(request, timestamp_of_reservation):
    """
    * Calculate the latest possible time where tickets are still reserved.
    * Check that 'created' timestamp of reservation item is not expired.
    * If expired, error message is being generated and redirect occurs.
    """
    latest_time_before_expired = timezone.now() - timedelta(
        minutes=settings.MINUTES_TICKET_RESERVATION
    )
    if timestamp_of_reservation < latest_time_before_expired:
        messages.add_message(
            request,
            messages.ERROR,
            _("Ticket reservation is too far in the past.")
        )
        return True
```

views.py

```
ticket_reservation_expired = ticket_reservation_expired(
    self.timestamp_of_reservation
)
if ticket_reservation_expired:
    return redirect(
        'events:detail',
        organizer=self.organizer,
        event=self.event,
    )
```

Comment: Why not just initialize it with None?. @PatrickArtner he is not modifying the variable inside the function he is calculating time delta using different params. So initializing with None will prevent him to accidentally accessing the variable if in case the function call does not return anything. Also, you can by default return False and return True only if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Your function only returns a value when a certain condition is met. When it is not met, nothing is returned. Good style is to either never return a value or always return one. Since if the condition is met you return True, return False when it is not met and your error should go away.

Also, in the code you posted, you named your variable and your function the same, this will lead you to no end of trouble.

Comment: I just figured it out, the reason I named them the same occurred the issues. After removing it, I could use my function. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. The return value will also give you trouble eventually, I suggest you fix it as well.

Comment: Done. I return False now as well.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is if the function does not return anything then it will throw an error as the variable is never defined because initialization of variable depends on the return value of the function. Just initialize the variable with `None`

```
ticket_reservation_expired_var = None
ticket_reservation_expired_var = ticket_reservation_expired(
    self.timestamp_of_reservation
)
if ticket_reservation_expired_var:
    return redirect(
        'events:detail',
        organizer=self.organizer,
        event=self.event,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you mad_. Great help! What resolved the issue was that the function and the variable shouldn't have the same names.

Comment: if a function does return nothing explicitly, python makes it return `None` implicitly.  Your texts suggests otherwise wich is wrong. Remove the `ticket_reservation_expired_var = None` - replass all content of the function with `pass` and print `ticket_reservation_expired_var` to verify

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is make that name a global reference inside the function:

```
global ticket_reservation_expired
```

That goes on the first line of the function. Alternatively, add another parameter to the function `ticket_reservation_expired` and just pass it in when you call the function so that the value is effectively 'transferred' to the function scope. However, changes to the variable will only take effect in the function's scope. So `global` is the option if you need to make any changes 'save' themselves after the function returns.